# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'rint' - How to replace or ignore text in the number column

Tags: python, string, pandas, attributeerror

I'm trying to add the calculated number columns to the csv file. However, the columns contain some text as string (which shouldn't be there), so when I try to run the code  I'm receiving an `AttributeError`. Any chance someone knows how to remove all the strings within the numbers column (i.e. make the string column into a float). Otherwise, I've tried ignoring the error, but except function doesn't help.

```
import pandas as pd

try:
    df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')        
    df['new_numbers_column'] = (df['numbers_column']+2)
    df.to_csv('test.csv', index=False)
except AttributeError:
    pass
```

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] with some sample data and your expected output? This can easily be done with either `pd.Series.str.extract` or just `pd.to_numeric`, but without sample data it's difficult to know if you need to actually extract numbers from a column with text, or simply coerce all of the bad rows to `NaN`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, here is the sample table

Comment: df = pd.DataFrame({'B':['a',7, 8],
                   'C':[7,8,9]})

Answer (score 0):

Use `errors` parameter:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'B':['a',7, 8], 'C':[7,8,9]})

df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
```

Output:

```
     B  C
0  NaN  7
1  7.0  8
2  8.0  9
```

Note: Pandas converts any column of numeric dtype with a NaN value to float.

Comment: thanks, this in theory should work, however nothing happens to the string when I run it. Do you know maybe why this happens (i.e. I've also updated Pandas, as I know this function might not work on older versions).

Comment: maybe because I'm reading my dataset from the file as: df = pd.read_csv('file')

Comment: Are you re-asssigning your function to the existing variable?  This apply is not an 'inplace' function, so you will need to re-assign to see the changes.

Comment: @IvanS If this solution helped you would you [upvote and accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?answertab=votes#tab-top)?